# Set all columns as index, or convert a dataframe to a multiindex series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have the following dataframe:

```
from    to  x     ratea
1       2   0.4   10
1       4   0.6   80
1       5   0.2   10
2       3   0.2   10
2       4   0.4   10
2       6   0.3   10
3       5   0.2   10
4       6   0.3   10
```

My goal is to have something like the following:

```
from    to      
1   2   x       0.4
1   2   ratea   10
1   4   x       0.6
1   4   ratea   80
1   5   x       0.2
1   5   ratea   10
2   3   x       0.2
2   3   ratea   10
2   4   x       0.4
2   4   ratea   10
2   6   x       0.3
2   6   ratea   10
3   5   x       0.2
3   5   ratea   10
4   6   x       0.3
4   6   ratea   10
```

How would I do this conversion?

PS `unstack()` did not help either (or maybe I did not use it probably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for set new index names:

```
s = df.set_index(['from','to']).stack().rename_axis(['from','to','val'])
print (s)

from  to  val  
1     2   x         0.4
          ratea    10.0
      4   x         0.6
          ratea    80.0
      5   x         0.2
          ratea    10.0
2     3   x         0.2
          ratea    10.0
      4   x         0.4
          ratea    10.0
      6   x         0.3
          ratea    10.0
3     5   x         0.2
          ratea    10.0
4     6   x         0.3
          ratea    10.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You don't know how many hours was wasted on this. You are a lifesaver :) You were so fast in answering that I can't accept the answer :) I have to wait 10 minutes apparently :)

Comment: Is there anyway that I could name that column so I could put all of those as index, i.e. how do I convert this to a multiindex series?